# Get a list of inbuild types

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to get a list of inbuilt types in Python including types included in imported modules? So the code would return something like `[int, list, dict str, etc..etc]`

The reason for doing this is as follows. I am an enthusiastic new user of Python. To help me ramp up I decided to commit to memory [inbuilt methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). To do this I used the Anki flash card program on Ubuntu. With this tool you can import a csv like file with questions and answers on each line separated by a delimiter.

Firstly I began with the build in methods. I found a suitable html table [here](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/built-in-function) and I wrote a script using BeautifulSoup4 to locate and convert this data to a csv format I could import into Anki. This worked great and I committed them all to memory. Then I realized that if I wanted to do the same with other data types I would need to find similar extensive lists which are not available on the site I used to start with.

I am considering taking each data type, running a dir on it to get all the methods that can act on it and then to call help() on each public method, for example `help(str.beginswith)`. I would then do some parsing to separate the method name from the description and write this to file in a csv format. Please don’t someone write this for me only pointers/hints please.

Comment: Since everything is an object, including types, this is not going to be straightforward. Add to that that some callables, such as `iter()`, give you various types based on what you called it on; `iter([])` returns a different type from `iter({})`. And any callable could produce instances of any type, really.

Comment: You could go through `globals` looking for objects which are subclasses of `type`. But why do you want this - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok i updated the original question with my reasons for it

Comment: I would also probably need to add a simulated keystroke for 'q' to end help() for each inbuilt type method

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`types`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) module:

```
>>> import types
>>> [t for t in vars(types).values() if isinstance(t, type)]
[<type 'int'>, <type 'type'>, <type 'code'>, ..., <type 'NoneType'>]
```

But, this is not complete as the documentation says:

> This module defines names for some object types that are used by the
>   standard Python interpreter, but not for the types defined by various
>   extension modules. Also, it does not include some of the types that
>   arise during processing such as the listiterator type. ...